# Arc 4 random on fetchresultscontroller with predicate - leave out all entries of one type

Tags: objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using arc 4 random to choose a random entry from my fetchresultscontroller but I need to leave out all entries of a certain category.  The column is "Category" and I dont want the random choice to include the category "Category2".  Below is my current code, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
- (NSIndexPath *)randomIndexPath
{

    NSInteger randomSection = arc4random_uniform([[fetchedResultsController sections]     count]);
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo =
    [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:randomSection];
    NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random_uniform( [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:randomIndex     inSection:randomSection];
    return indexPath;
}


- (IBAction)displayRandomEntry:(id)sender {
    if([[fetchedResultsController sections] count] <= 0)
        return;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self randomIndexPath];
    [self.myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    id object = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    RandomEntryDetailVC * controller;

    controller = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowRandomEntryDetailVC"];

    controller.currentItem = object;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: why not change your fetch predicate to exclude objects in category 2?

Comment: The fetch I'm using is the one that populates a table view and need to include category 2.  I tried making a new fetchedresultscontoller excluding category 2 but when I click the randomize button nothing happens. I'm sure it's bc this fetch doesn't correspond with the table view...how can I get around that? I like scrolling to the position of the randomly chosen entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any random number generator, the way you avoid specific values (or ranges of values) is to pick a number, and if that number is not in the range you like, you pick another number. Continue until you get a number you like. While in theory this is non-halting, in practice it will halt quite quickly for any sufficiently large subset.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I get that but I want to never pick a from a specific type of entries contained in the fetch.  One of my columns in my DB is "category" and there's a particular category I need to leave out of the random selection

Comment: So fetch a new list that filters that out with a predicate, and search on that list. Or just select index until you get an index that matches your criteria. Think about this problem as though it were records on index cards. How would you pick one you wanted? You'd either prune the stack and then draw, or you'd draw cards until you liked what you picked.

Comment: Good description.  Earlier I tried a few things but wasn't successful. I tried creating a BOOL within the randomize statement and checked for it when the fetch is called, which didnt work.  Can you give me an example? What do you suggest if I want to check in my Workout entity for a string contained in the "category" attribute?